# Java Scanner with regex delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Why does the following code return false?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("-v ");
sc.useDelimiter("-[a-zA-Z]\\s+");
System.out.println(sc.hasNext());
```

The weird thing is `-[a-zA-Z]//s+` will return true.

I also can't understand why this returns true:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(" -v");
sc.useDelimiter("-[a-zA-Z]\\s+");
System.out.println(sc.hasNext());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A scanner is used to break up a string into tokens. Delimiters are the **separators** between tokens. The delimiters are what **aren't** matched by the scanner; they're discarded. You're telling the scanner that `-[a-zA-Z]\\s+` is a delimiter and since `-v` matches that regex it skips it.

If you're looking for a string that matches the regex, use [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29).

If your goal really is to split a string into tokens then you might also consider [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), which is sometimes more convenient to use.

Comment: I am telling to use `-[a-zA-Z]\\s+` as the delimiter, -v is the input.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks John Kugelman, I think you're right.

Scanner can use customized delimiter to split input into tokens.
The default delimiter is a whitespace.

When delimiter doesn't match any input, it'll result all the input as one token:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("-v");
    sc.useDelimiter( "-[a-zA-Z]\\s+");
     if(sc.hasNext())
          System. out.println(sc.next());
```

In the code above, the delimiter actually doesn't get any match, all the input "-v" will be the single token.
**hasNext() means has next token**.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( "-v ");
    sc.useDelimiter( "-[a-zA-Z]\\s+");
     if(sc.hasNext())
          System. out.println(sc.next());
```

this will  match the delimiter, and the split ended up with 0 token, so the hasNext() is false.