# java 8 stream map check previous elements

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a question I have a big text file that i'm currently reading, I want to have a list of the words in it and also find spesific pairs in it.

An example of my dataset is:

```
A random text file . I am <pair-starter> first second <pair-ender> and it goes on and on,
and hopefully it ends .
```

Now I read the file with streams like

```
List<String> words = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename), Charset.forName("UTF-8")).
                     .map(line -> line.split("[\\s]+"))
                     .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                     .filter(this::filterPunctuation) //This removes the dot in example
                     .map(this::removePunctuation) //This removes the comma
                     //I think the method should be added here
                     .filter(this::removePairSpesifics) //To remove pair starter and ender
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now with this code I can get the clean words I get a list that contains `"A", "random", "text", "file", "I", "am", "first", "second", "and", "it", "goes", "on", "and", "on", "and", "hopefully", "it", "ends"` 
But I also want to get a hashmap that holds the pairs in it and I wonder if it is possible with adding a new method on the stream above. Couldn't find anything close to what I want from google, thanks in advance.

the method close to the one in my head is

```
private boolean pairStarted = false;
private String addToHashMap(String element){
    if previous element was pair starter
        pairStarted = true;
    else if pairStarted and element is not pairEnder
        MyPreviouslyConstructedHashMap.put(the previous one, element);
    else if element is pairEnder
        pairStarted = false;
    return element; 
} //This function will not change anything from the list as it returns the elements
  //But it'll add the hashmap first-second pair
```

---

My current solution is:

```
List<String> words = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename), Charset.forName("UTF-8")).
                     .map(line -> line.split("[\\s]+"))
                     .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                     .filter(this::filterPunctuation)
                     .map(this::removePunctuation)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList()); //Now not using removePairSpesifics 
//as I need to check for them.
for(int i=words.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if(words.get(i).equals("<pair-ender>")){ //checking from end to modify in the loop
        pairs.put(words.get(i-2), words.get(i-1));
        i = i-4;
        words.remove(i+1);
        words.remove(i+4);
    }
}
```

What I want to learn is to learn if it can be solved in the same stream as I read the values into the list.

Comment: how do you identify the key and value to add to map?

Comment: How you can get a `HashMap` while you use `Collectors.toList()`? Please, specify the desired output.

Comment: @EduardoDennis if it is between pair starter and pair ender, the first is going to be key and second will be the value, they are going to be unique.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis edited the question to add the desired method in my head

Comment: Can pairs span lines? Can there be multiple pairs per line? Show us your attempt at getting the pairs. Note that it won't look much like the code you posted, because once you split the line into words and stream them you lose context of adjacent words. Also, your split regex can be simplified from `[\\s]+` to `\\s+`.

Comment: @BrokenFrog: I asked for the expected output.

Comment: @Bohemian thanks for regex simplification, the pairs may have any kind  of whitespaces between them but their rule is they always consist 4 element starter, key, value, ender

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis the expected output is to not to modify the list and also add first-second pair to completely unrelated previously constructed hash map

Comment: I mean you could just create a new stream that filters from your new list for pairs? Or is the point that you want to do it all in the one stream?

Comment: @CowboyFarnz well I hope to do it in one go at one stream

Comment: @Bohemian my current way is to run currently is not using the last filter in the stream removePairSpesifics and collecting it. after collecting I search the list normal java way to find pairs and also remove pair spesifics while searching. A line can have more than one pair or maybe no pairs.

Comment: What about using [Collections.frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) , would this work?

Comment: @CowboyFarnz I can't see how it would help, can you elaborate a little?

Comment: @Broken Can a pair span across line breaks? I think you missed a key point in my previous comment. Once you split out words, and especially if you remove the pair markers, there's no way to tell words that are pairs from other words, so your code (and pseudo code) won't work. Please make an attempt and post it.

Comment: @BrokenFrog well I am just making an attempt at it but you would just use your filter to check for the same occurring strings and returns a Collector that accumulates the input elements into a new Set?

Comment: @Bohemian they can have any kind of whitespace between them including newlines, I think you had some misunderstandings, a pair always consists two words and before it is a pair starter and after it is a pair ender nothing else comes between these except whitespaces.

Comment: @CowboyFarnz It can accumulate pair starter and ender but I don't think it'll help in my case as what i want is there is more that one pairs and each pair will have a unique key and value.

Comment: If the pairs span multiple lines, you are using the wrong tool. Take a look at `Scanner` and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489570/java-scanner-with-regex-delimiter).

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner why does it matter? i split it before by \\s, so why does multiple lines matter?

Comment: @Broken I understand you completely. You are still missing my point: In a stream you have no access to the previous or following element, so you can't use your approach at all. Further, if you remove the markers, there's no way that *any* approach can find the pairts. With these points in mind, you need to rethink the whole approach and show some code that uses an approach that at least has a possibility of working.

Comment: @BrokenFrog The issue about pairs on different lines is that you have to either split and flatMap already (loosing the coupling of the pairs), or join all lines into one (potential huge) string first. That's why your for loop (or a scanner based alternative, or the mentioned custom Collector) work: they can accept word by word, while keeping the knowledge about the pairs. I have added a Collector solution to my answer that works for multiline pairs, as well.

Comment: From @MalteHartwig s answer I finally see what you all were trying to tell with the multiline problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I tried to separate the split into two splits, and it worked out quite well:

```
public void split(Stream<String> lines)
{
    Pattern pairFinder = Pattern.compile("<pair-starter|pair-ender>");
    Pattern spaceFinder = Pattern.compile("[\\s]+");

    Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> words = lines.flatMap(pairFinder::splitAsStream).flatMap(pairOrNoPair -> {
        if (pairOrNoPair.startsWith(">") && pairOrNoPair.endsWith("<"))
        {
            pairOrNoPair = pairOrNoPair.replaceAll("> +| +<", "");

            String[] pair = spaceFinder.split(pairOrNoPair);
            pairs.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
            return Arrays.stream(pair);
        }
        else
        {
            return spaceFinder.splitAsStream(pairOrNoPair.trim());
        }
    })
                              .filter(this::filterPunctuation) // This removes the dot in example
                              .map(this::removePunctuation) // This removes the comma
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(words);
    System.out.println(pairs);
}

// Output
// [A, random, text, file, I, am, first, second, and, it, goes, on, and, on, and, hopefully, it, ends]
// {first=second}

boolean filterPunctuation(String s)
{
    return !s.matches("[,.?!]");
}

String removePunctuation(String s)
{
    return s.replaceAll("[,.?!]", "");
}
```

What happens here? First, we split the line into pairs and non-pairs. For each of those, we check whether they are a pair. If so, we remove the markers and add the pair to the list. In any case, we split the chunk by spaces, flatten it, and procede word by word.

But this implementation only deals with the input line by line.

---

To tackle the issue with multi-line pairs, we can try a custom `Collector` approach. Look at this rather quick and dirty attempt:

```
String t1 = "I am <pair-starter> first second <pair-ender>, <pair-starter> and";
String t2 = " hopefully <pair-ender> it ends .";
split(Stream.of(t1, t2));

public void split(Stream<String> lines)
{
    PairResult result = lines.flatMap(Pattern.compile("[\\s]+")::splitAsStream)
                             .map(word -> word.replaceAll("[,.?!]", ""))
                             .filter(word -> !word.isEmpty())
                             .collect(new PairCollector());

    System.out.println(result.words);
    System.out.println(result.pairs);
}

// Output
// [I, am, first, second, and, hopefully, it, ends]
// {and=hopefully, first=second}

class PairCollector
    implements Collector<String, PairResult, PairResult>
{
    @Override
    public Supplier<PairResult> supplier()
    {
        return PairResult::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<PairResult, String> accumulator()
    {
        return (result, word) -> {
            if ("<pair-starter>".equals(word))
            {
                result.inPair = true;
            }
            else if ("<pair-ender>".equals(word))
            {
                if (result.inPair)
                {
                    result.pairs.put(result.words.get(result.words.size() - 2),
                                     result.words.get(result.words.size() - 1));
                    result.inPair = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // starter must be in another result, keep ender for combiner
                    result.words.add(word);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result.words.add(word);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<PairResult> combiner()
    {
        return (result1, result2) -> {
            // add completed pairs
            result1.pairs.putAll(result2.pairs);

            // use accumulator to finish split pairs
            BiConsumer<PairResult, String> acc = accumulator();
            result2.words.forEach(word2 -> acc.accept(result1, word2));

            return result1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<PairResult, PairResult> finisher()
    {
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics()
    {
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH));
    }
}

class PairResult
{
    public boolean                   inPair;
    public final List<String>        words = new ArrayList<>();
    public final Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<>();
}
```

This collector accepts word by word, and stores a bit of internal state to keep track of pairs. It should even work for parallel streams, combining the separate streams of words into one result.